# PageViewController current index

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

I want to set the value of a slider with the current index of a pageViewController.
My idea is to use this method but i dont know how I get the index...

```
-(void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
{

    if(completed)
    {

        //self.slider.value = THE INDEX;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you mean pageviewController.currentPage ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will have to implement custom method on your datasource,
that will return you index of view controller. You very likely have array with ViewControllers in  your datasource. so simple call like one below should do :

```
[pageViewController.datasource indexOfViewControler:[pageViewController.viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0]]; // index of viewcontroller is methond you need to implement on your datascource
```

Comment: Unfortunately, during gestures, the viewControllers method lies to you and returns the page where the gesture started even after it is no longer visible.  So if you're doing certain things like trying to debounce the page view, you'll have to recognize when the view's scroll position jumps by more than... say 90% of the width of the screen in a single event, and increment your page count....  Ick.  (Easy way to see this in action: walk the page from the second page in your view beyond the first view using two fingers.)

Answer (score -1):

you have to implement the method for getting index. you can do this simply by adding your viewController in NSArray .

```
NSArray * viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstViewController,secondViewController, nil];
```

& then get iindex like this:

```
self.slider.value=[viewControllers indexOfObject:[pageViewControlle.viewController]];
```